# Hyperlinks Not Working on iOS and Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, hyperlink

http://www.lifesalonspa.com/truro/staff/

There is no problem on PC/desktop Etc. big screen device but on mobile and only on the section( http://prntscr.com/59xtwn ) of the web site(on other page and section is ok) all type of hyperlink is not working.
I've tried by those Attributes
rel="external" data-ajax="false" ETC.

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of `onclick="window.location = $(this).attr('href')"`?? Why not just remove that and leave a standard `href` attribute?

Comment: Yes I've already tried by a standard href attribute,
EX: <a href="http://domain.com">link</a>
Not working!

Comment: Have you tried using a valid absolute URL including the protocol, eg `http://domain.com`

Comment: Yes I've tried already you can check there "Valid FB link" link on your IOS or Android device. (Working on PC! But not on mobile.)